# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/hanminsoo/Documents/photogram/photogram/photo

Tags: python, django, path, static-content, django-pipeline

Using pipeline...
I order

```
python photogram/manage.py collectstatic
```

and

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:
/Users/hanminsoo/Documents/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/dist/static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:
```

I order 'yes'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "photogram/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/photogram/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/photogram/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/photogram/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
 File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/photogram/lib/python3.5/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/management/__init__.py", line 41, in new_execute
return original_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/photogram/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/photogram/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 176, in handle
collected = self.collect()
File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/photogram/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 98, in collect
for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/photogram/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 112, in list
for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/photogram/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 28, in get_files
directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
File "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/photogram/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 299, in listdir
for entry in os.listdir(path):

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/hanminsoo/Documents/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/settings/static'
Sentry is attempting to send 2 pending error messages
Waiting up to 10 seconds
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

I don't know what is my problem...

here's my code...(photogram/settings/static.py)

```
import os

from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin, ManifestFilesMixin

from .base import PROJECT_ROOT_DIR
from .base import BASE_DIR

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, "dist", "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, "dist", "media")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")),
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)

PIPELINE = {
    'STYLESHEETS': {
        'application': {
              'source_filenames': (
              'css/*.css',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'css/photogram.css',
        },
    },
    'JAVASCRIPT': {
    }
}
```

> settings.BASE_DIR
>   '/Users/hanminsoo/Documents/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/settings'
>
> settings.STATIC_ROOT
>   '/Users/hanminsoo/Documents/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/static'
>
> settings.PROJECT_ROOT_DIR
>   '/Users/hanminsoo/Documents/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram'
>
> settings.STATICFILES_DIRS
>   ['/Users/hanminsoo/Documents/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/settings/static']

Please help me.

Comment: double check if you have such a directory, `ls /Users/hanminsoo/Documents/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/settings/static`

Comment: emm... is that means I must 
mkdir /Users/hanminsoo/Documents/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/photogram/set‌​tings/static??

Comment: although it shouldn't have happened, might happen due to permission issues. So worth giving a shot.

Comment: oh.... thank you "dnit13" i solved problem..(I change path STATICFILES_DIRS )
but new error makes me confused...
     (((((pipeline.exceptions.CompressorError: b'env: yuglify: No such file or directory\n')))))
Can you give me a hint for this error?

Comment: Did you solved it??